# Force Accelio to use RDMA

Tags: c, hpc, rdma

We are using Accelio (https://github.com/accelio) underneath JXIO in order to send packages over the RDMA protocol.

> JXIO is Java API over AccelIO (C library).
>
> AccelIO (http://www.accelio.org/) is a high-performance asynchronous
>   reliable messaging and RPC library optimized for hardware
>   acceleration. RDMA and TCP/IP transport are implemented, and other
>   transports, such as shared-memory can take advantage of efficient and
>   convenient API.

The problem for us is that Accelio is currently using the TCP protocol instead of RDMA, how can we build it to use the latter?

Comment: There seem to be a flag for that but RDMA actually seems to be enabled by default:
`--enable-rdma #enable rdma transport - default:yes`

Comment: Are you using an RDMA-capable network adapter? If you are binding your app to an RDMA device, then Accelio should notice that and utilize RDMA.

Comment: Yes, we figured we had to recompile it in order to enable RDMA (it's not enabled by default). Now we're getting the expected latency (event though we unexpectedly get high spikes when the messages rate is low..)